# Is this “by this time” in “On Liberty” a typo for “at this time”?

Tags: nineteenth-century-english, typographical-errors

Here is a passage from *On Liberty*, written by J.S. Mill:

> This mode of thought, or rather perhaps of feeling, was common among the last generation of European liberalism, in the Continental section of which it still apparently predominates. Those who admit any limit to what a government may do, except in the case of such governments as they think ought not to exist, stand out as brilliant exceptions among the political thinkers of the Continent. A similar tone of sentiment might **by this time** have been prevalent in our own country, if the circumstances which for a time encouraged it, had continued unaltered.

Mill states that *this mode of thought . . . was common among the last generation of European liberalism*, of course including that of British one. However, since *by this time* implies that specific actions have been somehow completed before then, it has the completely paradoxical implication that **the attitude once common in Britain might have completed to prevail itself in its country by now (but actually it is not)**.

Is it a typo? At least all the texts I have seen do not mention this problem, and some friends of mine agreed with this hypothesis. Please be it noted that in this context, I guess, any philosophical/political knowledge should not necessarily be needed. I would rather like to hear some opinions from a grammatical point of view.

Comment: Both *by this time* and *at this time* amount to the same thing in the sentence.

Comment: Not a typo.  Firstly, you're ignoring the important qualifier "Continental," which refers to Europe's continent, which doesn't include Great Britain.  He then says that the thinking from the continent might have "by this time" (i.e. by now) also arisen in Britain, but it didn't.  It could have, since the conditions that encourage such thinking were also present in Britain, but those conditions were somehow altered/removed.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @cruthers I think “This mode of thought, or rather perhaps of feeling, was common among the last generation of European liberalism, in the Continental section of which it still apparently predominates.” means “the thinking was common in Europe including Great Britain and still predominates only in Europe’s continent”. Well, but maybe the point is whether or not it was prevalent rather than present. Just because it was common in Europe doesn’t mean that it was prevalent in Britain, am I right?

Comment: I'm afraid we *do* actually have to get into the political history, because I for one don't have a good answer for: What distinction is Mills drawing when he talks about "European liberalism" as a whole and "the Continental section" as a part? (However, I do strongly suspect that he would not have intended for "European" to include Great Britain in this usage.)

Comment: Oh I see it now.  I had read "in the Continental section of which" as a further qualification of among which people the original thoughts were held.  Very confusing because "Continental section of which" refers to Europe, but "Europe" is not presented as a standalone referent.  So, yes, I agree with your further point that present does not equal prevalent.